# What are the leading EJB platform providers, such as WebSphere, etc.?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am looking at this question from someone with a Microsoft background. If I wanted to get to know the EJB world, who are the leading players in terms of implementations?

Comment: What are you looking for in your EJB container?

Answer (score 2):

Open source implementations of the EJB spec would be Glassfish from Sun, Geronimo from Apache, JBOSS from JBOSS.org (the open source version, not the Red Hat one), or OpenEJB running under Tomcat.

If you have cash to burn on licenses, try WebLogic from Oracle/BEA or WebSphere from IBM.

If money is no object, I think WebLogic is the best tool on the market.

If money is a concern, I think Glassfish gives you the best chance of being on the bleeding edge of the standard implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The leading commercial providers are Weblogic (now owned by Oracle) and Websphere.

By far the most commonly used application server is JBoss, which is free. Other free app servers include Glassfish and Geronimo.

IMHO there is increasingly little reason to use a full-blown app server. Spring+JPA/Hibernate in a WEb container like Tomcat or Jetty is far more common. As of EJB 3.1 you will be able to deploy EJBs in a Web container.